# OpenVPN Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection

Tags: debian, networking, openvpn

I am using Debian on a VPS and now I need to connect it to my university vpn using OpenVPN. I have .ovpn file imported and I can see the connection in `nmcli c`. But when I issue `nmcli c up myvpn` I get `Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection.`

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NetworkManager fails with "Could not find source connection"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438224/networkmanager-fails-with-could-not-find-source-connection)

Comment: @roaima unfortunately, no. I connect to the server via SSH and I can't use GUI.

Comment: Ignore the answers that use the GUI. The remainder seem plausible

Comment: Don't seem to get anything useful from there..

Comment: Does your interface have a default gateway set, if it does not, then you encountered the same issue as the linked issue. Please provide the output of `ip r` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated the .ovpn file and sent it to the server using powershell and SCP. Then recreated the connection and managed to set it up.